# How to export ocean simulation to .json file with the animated modifier?

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation, three.js

I got my blend file from [here](http://www.blendhelp.com/blend/wave.rar) and I want to export this as a three.js json file so i can load it to browser. I managed to do that but as result i get the 1st frame of the model and not the model animated like it is when i play it at the timeline. What i want is to animate the ocean as it animates when it is in blender.. How can i achieve that? I use the following code to load to three js:

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            loader.load( "wave.json", function( geometry, materials ) {
            wave= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
            wave.position.set(10,10,10);
            wave.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
scene.add(wave);
```

any help?

Comment: Have you already read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246598/three-js-exporting-json-models-from-blender-including-textures ?

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866748/exporting-a-simple-model-with-texture-from-blender-to-three-js ?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The answer i came up is to export as morph animation and use morphTargets=true and morphTargetInfluences[] to update frames.:)

Comment: Sounds good. Can you share your solution?

Comment: I shared some of the solution [to this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19185/how-to-export-ocean-simulation-from-blender-with-reflection)..if you are interested at the animation part i can tell you.. :)